# Setting minimal consumer polling interval in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to set up consumer's polling interval in order to process 1 message per minute and couldn't find appropriate setting. I have 1 consumer for topic.

I'm using aiokafka for python. Found some settings like request_timeout_ms, fetch_max_wait_ms, max_poll_interval_ms but description doesn't say that any of these settings set up polling interval.